# Starting a background service for only once and stop once the task is completed

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, android-service, autocompletetextview

I am using a auto-complete text view in my activity and i wrote a service to get data from server in the same activity after completing service i have enabled that auto-complete text view because when user start typing in that text view the data i got from server start gets filtering, every thing up to here is working fine but every time i came to same activity my service start executing i just want that my service get call for only once and also the user can search from auto complete text view once my data come from server.

**MyActivity Code**

```
@Override
 protected void onStart() {



    if(CarproApp.getInstance().namesList != null) {
    //enable textfield if you have already fetched the data from server :)
        debitornameET.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(MyService.MY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        //Start our own service

    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerAccountActivity.this,
            MyService.class);
    //intent.putExtra("INIT_DATA", "Data passed from Activity to Service in startService");
    startService(intent);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}

private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        namelist = arg1.getStringArrayListExtra("listnames");
        System.out.println("PRINTING" + namelist);
        debitornameET.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BackGround Task   Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        CarproApp.getInstance().namesList = namelist;

    }

   debitornameET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    //  MyWebRequestService.listVal; 
                    debitorcodeET.setText("");
                    debitorCode = "";
                    Collections.sort(namelist);//here i am getting null when i came back to same activity
                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,namelist);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    debitornameET.setThreshold(1);
                    debitornameET.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


                }
            });
        }
```

**Service.Class**

```
 public class MyService extends Service {

    final public static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";
    //String initData;
    private SendHttpRequest reqService;
    public static ArrayList<String> servicelist;  

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        servicelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    //  initData = intent.getStringExtra("INIT_DATA");

        new AsynchCall().execute();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    class AsynchCall extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String qryService = "SELECT DEBITOR_NAME FROM DEBITORS ";
            reqService = new SendHttpRequest(qryService);
            try {
                reqService.ExecuteQuery();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<reqService.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                servicelist.add(reqService.getRow(i)[1]);
                System.out.println("TEXTVIEWDATAAAAAAAAa" + reqService.getRow(i)[1]);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("listnames", servicelist);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

** CarproApp Class**

```
        public class CarproApp extends Application {

        private static CarproApp sInstance;
        public ArrayList<String> namesList;

        public static CarproApp getInstance() {
            return sInstance;
        }

        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            sInstance = this;


        }



    }
```

Because the data coming from server is so large i don't want it to store in local database. My code is working but every time i came to activity the service call gets executed which i don't want. Please guide me

Comment: @piyush-daryapurkar : I have updated my answer check mainActivity onStart method :) now everything should be fine :)

Comment: If you still have a issue :) lemme know :) there should not be though :D

Comment: Hey I have updated onStart() method of main activity and onTextChanged() as well :) Simple reason for null :) you are using namelist property of MainActivity inside onTextChange :) bhai mere, when you change the activity and come back to same activity :) activity ke saare property recreate hogaana ?? so value to null hee rahegana bhai :D So use application instance value :D thats the reason we added it remember ?? :D

Comment: kya hua bhai ?? chala code ?? Is everything fine now ???

Comment: @SandeepBhandari  
bro after all the stupid mistakes(kolaveri di) i made your code works like charm thankss alot atleast u r wid me upto my output thanx for ur all efforts .. :) :)

Comment: You should also take a look at IntentService class. It's by far more simple and flexible to use than Service.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make use of Application class :) Application class gets executed once for the entire life cycle of your app :) That means onCreate of Application class gets called when you launch app and onDestroy gets called when you kill the app :)

So Application class is persistant for the entire life cycle of your app :) I believe thats what you need :)

Call your service in OnCreate() of your application class :) Once you get the data save it in a property of Application class :) So whenever you come back to the Activity read the data from the property of Application class :)

Here is what you can do :)

```
public class yourApplicationName extends Application{ 
     private static yourApplicationName sInstance;
     public ArrayList<String> namesList;

     public static yourApplicationName getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }
}
```

In order to make use of this application class as your application class you will have to specify it in AndroidManifest.xml :)

```
<application
    android:name=".yourApplicationName"
```

and in your,

private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    namelist = arg1.getStringArrayListExtra("listnames");
    System.out.println("PRINTING" + namelist);
    debitornameET.setEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BackGround Task         Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    yourApplicationName.getInstance().namesList = nameList;
}

debitornameET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //  MyWebRequestService.listVal; 
                debitorcodeET.setText("");
                debitorCode = "";
                Collections.sort(CarproApp.getInstance().namesList);//here i am getting null when i came back to same activity, abhi nai aayega error :P
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,CarproApp.getInstance().namesList);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                debitornameET.setThreshold(1);
                debitornameET.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


            }
        });
    }
```

To enable your textfield when you comeback to the MainActivity :) just check if Application instance property is empty or not :)

```
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
       if(yourApplicationName.getInstance().namesList != null) {
            //enable textfield if you have already fetched the data from server :)
            debitornameET.setEnabled(true);
       }
       else{
            myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(MyService.MY_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);

            //you dont have to call service very time buddy :D call only once enough :)
            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerAccountActivity.this,
        MyService.class);
            //intent.putExtra("INIT_DATA", "Data passed from Activity to Service in startService");
            startService(intent);
       }
  }
```

Hope I was of little help there :) Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down vote :) Helps me understand my mistake

Comment: getting null pointer in this line yourApplicationName.getInstance().namesList = namelist;

Comment: @PiyushDaryapurkar : Have you set the yourApplicationName as your application class buddy ??? have you changed AndroidManifest.xml ??? And I have updated the yourApplicationName class onCreate method :) can you please confirm have used the updated code buddy :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes bro.. i have done exactly what you have said i wrote a separate class and write the method as you said also i have register it in manifest also i get null pointer in onStart() if condition

Comment: Bro are you getting null on nameList property of yourApplicationName class ?? is that what you are saying buddy ???

Comment: @pskink yes i have tried that to but i am getting this The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Comment: @SandeepBhandari in onstart() method you have check one condition (myappname.getInstance().namesList != null) here i am getting null pointer

Comment: @PiyushDaryapurkar : Dude can you check your public void onCreate() method of your myappname ??? is this statement sInstance = this; there buddy ??

Comment: @SandeepBhandari no i have change one line which you wrote in onReceive() method of broadcast receiver  yourApplicationName.getInstance().namesList = nameList; to yourApplicationName.getInstance().namesList = namelist;

Comment: Bhai, can you please update your question with updated AndroidManifest.xml, yourApplication class code and onRecieve() method please :) Am making guesses blindly here without code :( and this is a well tested and used code cant fail ever buddy :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Done bro check the edited one ,in manifest
 <activity android:name="com.carpro.rentproapp.CarproApp"

Comment: @piyush-daryapurkar : Bhai manifest update must be wrong :) if you have updated it as <activity android:name="com.carpro.rentproapp.CarproApp" /> it should be <application android:name="com.carpro.rentproapp.CarproApp" .../> can you check once :D

Comment: you must be able to see Application tag correct for that you need to add android:name tag with value of your CarproApp class :) and then put a break point in CarproApp's onCreate() method and check if control reaching there or not :) I guess only issue is you havent configured your Application tag properly bhai :) you set it it will work like a charm :) mark my words :) still have issue just post AndroidManifest.xml :) lemme fix that :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes it is working fine now but my onRecieve() of broadcast reciever not gets called now :(

Comment: @piyush-daryapurkar : bhai its because your myReciever is not instantiated yet :) ek kaam karo :) keep your my activity code as it is i mean call your service in myactivity only :) lemme update the code check it and I promise problem will be solved ok :) dont worry :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari thanx for ur efforts  i have updated my code as you said but  i am getting null pointer when i came back to same activity i have mention in the code where i am getting null pointer.

Comment: @piyush-daryapurkar : bhai :D why this kolevari di :P you are making 2 mistakes here :) lemme copy paste the whole code ok :) just use it as it is and tell me if you still have issue :P

Comment: bro after all the stupid mistakes(kolaveri di) i made your code works like charm thankss alot atleast u r wid me upto my output thanx for ur all efforts .. :) :)

Comment: @piyush-daryapurkar : you are always welcome :) Mistakes are meant to happen :D after all we are humans :) Sorry I din see your comment here and ended up asking "kya hua" when I saw you accepted the answer :D Have great evening :D and happy coding :D